# When I change the base href in index.html file I connot login okta service

Tags: angular, okta, okta-signin-widget

When I change the base href to this "./" I connot login okta service.
[!callback page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du8bp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du8bp.png)

// this is my login component

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OKTA_AUTH } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
import OktaSignIn from '@okta/okta-signin-widget';

import myAppConfig from '../../config/my-app-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  oktaSignin: any;

  constructor(@Inject(OKTA_AUTH) private oktaAuth: OktaAuth) {

    this.oktaSignin = new OktaSignIn({
      logo: 'assets/images/logo.png',
      baseUrl: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
      clientId: myAppConfig.oidc.clientId,
      redirectUri: myAppConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
      useClassicEngine: true,
      authParams: {
        pkce: true,
        issuer: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer,
        scopes: myAppConfig.oidc.scopes
      }
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oktaSignin.remove();

    this.oktaSignin.renderEl({
      el: '#okta-sign-in-widget'},
      (response: any) => {
        if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
        }
      },
      (error: any) => {
        throw error;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

// and this is my config file for okta. name of the config file is myAppconfig

```
export default {

    oidc: {
        clientId: '#########',
        issuer: 'https://######.okta.com/oauth2/default',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/login/callback',
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
    }

}
```

I am trying to make a desktop app in Angular. And I am using Electron. So I have to change base href.Normaly If I don't change base href I can login okta.